# How to solve this 2-D differential equation

Tags: integration, differential

Here's the given equation

$\dfrac{dAS(t)}{dt} = -AS(t)$

$\dfrac{dAR(t)}{dt} = -AI(t) + AI(t)*AS(t)$

Here's what I have done:

Rearranging and integrating equation one
$\dfrac{dAS(t)}{AS(t)} = -dt$

$\displaystyle∫\dfrac{dAS(t)}{AS(t)} = -∫ dt$

Then $AS(t)$ will be
$AS(t) = D*\exp(-t)$

On substituting on equation two and rearranging we have,

$\dfrac{dAR(t)}{dt} + AI(t)(1 - D\exp(-t)) = 0$

I hope I am on the right track till here and it's getting messed up when I am trying to integrate. Is everything correct till here? If so please help me integrate this equation.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an edit): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance

Comment: I have made the edit.Please look into it and any help is appreciated

Comment: @Arjun You didn't edit enough. Write mathematics with Mathjax, as used in this site, otherwise it is very hard to follow what you wrote.

Comment: Iam really sorry for the poor presentation of the question as I am new here, I am having a test tomorrow so I am in a bit hurry,I have made the edit suggested, Please help me solve this equation

Comment: @Arjun You still need to provide more context. Where did this problem come from? What are $AR(t)$, $AS(t)$ and $AI(t)$?

Comment: They are nodes in a information diffusion system.AS node will get converted to AR node with probability of alpha for a given time period

Comment: @Arjun With all due respect, you still have not added enough additional context. What is $AI(t)$? What do nodes in an information diffusion system have to do with solving a differential equation? Where did this problem come from? I suggest you edit your question to include this information and be specific about it. Without this information, it is very difficult to understand what you are talking about and what you are trying to do.